# Why not forked subtask executed not on main thread?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, zio

I'm new to zio, so i may miss something.

zio dependency:

> compile group: 'dev.zio', name: 'zio_2.12', version: '1.0.0-RC16'

I have a simple sample:

```
import zio._

object Sample2 {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val runtime = new DefaultRuntime {}

    val a = ZIO.effect {
      println(s"A - ${Thread.currentThread().getName}")
      Thread.sleep(1000)
      println(s"A - ${Thread.currentThread().getName}")
      println("Finish A")
      2
    }

    val b = ZIO.effect {
      println(s"B - ${Thread.currentThread().getName}")
      Thread.sleep(5000)
      println(s"B - ${Thread.currentThread().getName}")
      println("Finish B")
      2
    }

    val c = ZIO.effect {
      println(s"C - ${Thread.currentThread().getName}")
      Thread.sleep(3000)
      println(s"C - ${Thread.currentThread().getName}")
      println("Finish C")
      2
    }

//   example A
//    val r = for {
//      x <- a
//      y <- b
//    } yield c.map(_ * x * y)

//   example B    
val r = for {
  fiberX <- a.fork
  fiberY <- b.fork
  x <- fiberX.join
  y <- fiberY.join
  z <- c
} yield x * y * z  

    val result = runtime.unsafeRun(r)
    println(s"Result: $result")
  }
}
```

If i run example A then all efects will be executed on main thread what is expected.

If i run example B then i expect that effects A and B will be executed on separate threads (fibers) and effect C - on main. In result i get that all effects was executed on separate threads (fibers).

Is it correct behaviour? Is it possible to return to the main thread?

Comment: I believe that is the expected behaviour. If you need to have tasks run on specific executors you can use `ZIO.lock(executor)`. I suppose with a single-thread executor, that can be used to put it on a specific thread as well.

Comment: Why is `r` a `ZIO[ZIO]` so that you need to flatten it? Why not also put `c` inside the comprehension?

Comment: @Thilo, fixed.
Also i've mentioned that if i place C effect first and then execute A and B then C will be executed on main thread. If C will be last - then on another thread. It reminds me java CompletableFuture with *Async ops

Answer (score 2):

Fibers are not threads. They are a lightweight abstraction that run on top of a dedicated threadpool. You will typically have many fibers running on a smaller amount of threads.

When you call something blocking, you need to use a dedicated threadpool in order not to block other fibers. ZIO provides one by default when you use `ZIO.effectBlocking`.

More details: https://zio.dev/docs/overview/overview_basic_concurrency#fibers